# ee3 bloqs and relationships

Tags: relationships, ee3, blocks

I have a channel that uses a Bloqs fieldtype in ee3. One of the defined blocks has a native relationship in it. I can output all the content from the related entries without a problem, but was wondering if anyone else had a problem with the total_results variable.

```
{exp:channel:entries}
{bloqs_field}
  {block_type}
    total: {relationfield:total_results}
    {relationfield}
        {relationfield:title} ({relationfield:count})
    {/relationfield}
  {/block_type}
{/bloqs_field}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Everything above works as expected - except the output of {relationfield:total_results} which is always "1" regardless of the number of items selected > 0.

Has anyone else run across this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe to access the total_results tag it needs to be inside the relationship tags, currently you have it sitting outside the tag.

Comment: Hmm. Could have sword I had replied to this, but I don't see it here... Regardless of where I put the tag, the output remains the same.